# In firefox is a ajax call deleted before a redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, redirect

First, in Chrome this working every time 100% and in Firefox not working 100%.

In a click-event, I want only submit data with ajax to the server for statistics. There is no response needed, it should only submit the data to the server. After submitting ajax-data the visitor should immediately redirect to another page. **I can't do redirect after ajax callback or something like async=false, because the calculation takes its time and visitors should not waiting seconds.**

The only solution that I can see, its to use setTimeout() as a workaround for Firefox, so the ajax call is successfully submitted and redirect called after a period of milliseconds. Is there a preferred documented value in milliseconds for this task? So its working 100% for all future versions of Firefox.

Actual I can only guess a value that working on my pc in my actual firefox version. Is there maybe an official value for this in firefox?

Is this may be an issue in Firefox? 
I can fully understand that async=true don't give callbacks with outside redirects.

But I don't need callbacks, I want only to submit data with ajax. Why firefox kills these requests silently? 
There is no trace in the network.

Comment: have you heard of `sendBeacon`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jaromanda for this useful hint with sendBeacon.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

```
var fd = new FormData(); 
fd.append('var1', 123); 
fd.append('var2', 'text'); 
navigator.sendBeacon('ajax.php', fd);
```

In PHP you can access on server with

```
$_POST['var1']
```

Hint: with redirect after sendBeacon() like

```
window.location.href = url;
```

its said in network-tab status "PENDING" with 0 Byte transfered and this never change, but the request was successful submitted. Without redirect its have HTTP-Status 200, so is a bit strange.